# How to extract specific value from excel column using python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Need to extract specific value from excel column using python pandas dataframe

The column Product that I am trying to extract looks the below & need to extract only Product # from it. The column also has other numbers but the Product # always comes after the term 'UK Pro' & Product # could be 3 to 4 digit number in a particular row of data.

In[1]:

df['Product'].head()

**#Dataframe looks like this:**

Out[1]:

Checking center : King 2000 :  UK Pro 1000 : London

Checking center : Queen 321 : UK Pro 250 : Spain

CC : UK Pro 3000 : France

CC : UK Pro  810 : Poland

**Expected Output:**

**Product #**

1000

250

3000

810

Started with this:

df['Product #'] = df1['Product'].str.split(':').str[1]

But this does split only based on the first two occurrence of : operator.

Then tried this:

df1['Product #'] = df1['Product'].str.split('UK Pro', 1).str[0].str.strip()

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
df["Product #"] = df["Product"].str.extract("UK Pro (\d+)", expand=False)
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
   Product #
0        NaN
1        NaN
2       1000
3        NaN
4        NaN
5        250
6        NaN
7       3000
8        NaN
9        810
10       NaN
```